# How to get the specific array data from and array in php and store it

Tags: php, arrays, database

I have this php code to select studentid's from database table and print out the students with value 1 in the Project1 column.

```
      <?PHP
      include_once("connectionToProjectChoice.php"); 
      /* Check column 1 (Project1) in tbl_studentchoice*/ 
      $check = "SELECT * FROM tbl_studentchoice WHERE Project1 = '1'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $check);
      
      if ($result->num_rows > 0){ //check
            $student = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $array[$row['studentid']]=$row['Project1'];
            }   
      }
      print_r($array);  
      ?>
```

The result I get is [image: Result]

So my question is is there a way I could store studentname(c125582333) and (c12558242)separately so I could make an If statement because I want to compare them in the next section of the code.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Could you explain more?

Comment: What I wanted was to get the studentid of the students from the database table where they have value 1 in the Project1 column. So I want to like have $student1 = c12558233 and $student2 = c12558242

Comment: I answered what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if ($result->num_rows > 0){ //check
        $student = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $array[] = [
                  'studentid' => $row['studentid']],
                  'Project1' => $row['Project1']
           ];
        }   
  }
  print_r($array);
```

It might be easier building your array differently?

Comment: Thank you ! You gave me an idea. so when I put `echo $array[0]['studentid']."<br>";` I got the first student number

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
      include_once("connectionToProjectChoice.php"); 
      /* Check column 1 (Project1) in tbl_studentchoice*/ 
      $check = "SELECT * FROM tbl_studentchoice WHERE Project1 = '1'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $check);

      if ($result->num_rows > 0){ //check
            $i = 1;
            $students = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $students['student'.$i++]=$row['studentid'];
            }   
      }
      print_r($students);
      extract($students); //gives you $student1, $student2, ...  
      ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Found what I what I needed to do but this way is good also

Comment: I don't like knocking anyones answer but i can see two big issues with this answer that would lead to future complications. 1) $students['student'.$i++]   there is no reason for the 'student' string here and will only result in you needing to remove it later for display purposes or anything else. 2) do not rely on extract.. a very nice an handy shortcut on occasion but prevent ide's from knowing where "$student1" come from and has also been proven to be security risks in some cases.

Comment: @John, I just made a compatible code with Anthony's request in the comment of the question. I never code like that ;)